# how to deploy java embedded suit on openwrt system

Tags: java, openwrt

1. download jre from here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/java-embedded-suite/index.html
2. upload jre directory to OpenWrt
3. test it:

> ./deploydir/jre/bin/java -version

but failure, Error Message：

> /bin/ash: ./java: not found

i am very confused about it.What's wrong?

Add information:

i use file command, and there is the output:
./java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), ......

Answer (score 1):

You can't just do that, two reasons I can think of right now:

1. Quite probably the binary `java` is not compiled for the same CPU type; in your case the command file shows that the `java` binary contains code for Intel 80386; I don't think that's the kind of CPU you have in your device.
2. Even if your device had an Intel 80386, the `java` binary uses dynamic libraries (have you already installed them?), which, again should be compiled for the kind of processor you're using

You need to get the source code for java (maybe in the OpenJDK website) and compile it for the platform you're using it, same for the libraries it uses.

Comment: First，Thanks. About your advise, cause i use OpenWrt system on VitualBox which run on my PC ,and i am very sure the system is a X86 OS.The next one, cause i use the jrecreate to custom my JRE, so i think i has the full dynamic libraries to run java.I am so sorry that i still do not solve the problem.

Comment: Some time ago I was working with an embedded system, when I executed a dynamically linked ELF file for which I had forgotten installing the dependencies I always got "xxx not found" instead of something like "dependencies missing" it's anoying but I suppose its because the size of the file should be as small as possible that there is no space for storing more detailed string messages. Anyway, in your host environment try using `ldd` (man ldd) it will tell you the dependencies for a given ELF object (library or executable)